# Win32 development - String related datatypes in C++

Tags: string, winapi, pointers, types, character-encoding

I was going to start with Win32 app development. Before I could get the first window to display i was ready to give up! I was overwhelmed by the number of datatypes you need to know about before you can write a simple WinMain and WndProc. (unless you copy-paste of course!)

Especially these -

LPSTR

LPCSTR

LPWSTR

LPCWSTR

Can someone point me to the right article that explains these with respect to Win32 programming? Which ones should I know about, which ones are needed in what situation, *when* to go for Unicode, what is multi-byte char set, and all the related stuff.

And the conversion to/from these datatypes to char* and char[] and whatnot, when calling Win32 API functions is a pain.

It is all so confusing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: don't forget BSTR, _wchar_t or the many many wrapper classes: CComBstr, CString, CAtlString, STL::String, _bstr_t.
Best thing about C++ is writing your own string implementation ;)

Comment: okay, you just made my head spin...

Comment: depending on the platforms you work on you typically only need one or two. For windows development _bstr_t and CString is all I end up using for the most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is relatively simple:

LPSTR = zero-terminated string of `char`

LPCSTR = *constant* zero-terminated string of `char` (C == *constant*)

LPWSTR = zero-terminated string of `wchar_t` (W == wide character)

LPCWSTR = *constant* zero-terminated string of `wchar_t` (C and W)

For details and explanations see e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide1.aspx

The linked article also contains advice when to use Unicode in your application and when not.

Comment: +1 - hey, just had a glance at the article. Looks like it answers a LOT of my string/charset questions. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, it is ridiculous at first, but makes some kind of sense after a while.

Comment: Going through it... It is as if that article was made to order! :) Couldn't have asked for more.